# Spring property Inject full property object to bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, dependency-properties

Ihave property class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-api")
public class MyApiProperties {

    ...

    private MyClient myClient; 

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class MyClient {
        private String host;
        private long connectionTimeout;
        private long receiveTimeout;
    }
}
```

I can config it:

```
my-api:
  my-client:
    host: http://1...
    connection-timeout: 30000
    receive-timeout: 60000
```

And I can Inject it:

```
@Value("${my-api.my-client.host}")
private String host;
```

**But can I inject full object like this?**

```
@Value("${my-api.my-client}")
private MyClient myClient;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Value property for custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063171/spring-value-property-for-custom-class)

Comment: No. It isn't a component and `@Value` doesn't work like that. You can inject the enclosing `MyApiProperties` as you should as the properties are part of that object.