# Default value as Duration at @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to specify *default value* for an instance variable which is of type *java.time.Duration*

The default value which I pass is being read as String, causing IllegalStateException

My class

```
public class Test {
  @Value("${kafka.consumer.commit.interval:5s}")
  private Duration commitInterval;

  .
  .
  .

}
```

Exception:

```
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'commitInterval'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration'; 
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: I think you have to create a custom PropertyEditorSupport. This SO explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063171/spring-value-property-for-custom-class

Comment: or you can use Spring EL and use Duration.of(commitInterval, TemporalUnit) or another factory method.

Comment: What is dependencies do the project have?

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi If this conversion issue is resolved, dependencies will be automatically satisfied. That is just appearing, beacuse the bean bearing this code, could not be built !

Comment: I do a sample example and i just have `spring-boot-starter` without any extra dependencies, and it's work fine.  This is why i ask you about dependencies. @AdityaRewari

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi ok.. letme check with a smaple progarm

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi I checked with a sample program.. it surprisingly doesnt throw an error, but prints NULL . same happend with you ?

Comment: @AdityaRewari,  Oh i got it, Your class doesn't annotated by `@Component` or `@Service`. so there is no any spring bean definition for it.
So spring not the one who create the instance, you do that.

Comment: @IbrahimAlTamimi ..it worked with Annotations. Thanks a ton !!!

Comment: You welcome @AdityaRewari

Comment: Just to protect yourself from this error to shown again, try to make it initialized from constructer with final property. It will help you to know if your bean creation is going well or not. @AdityaRewari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SpEL expression directly to invoke factory method of `Duration` class :

```
@Value("${kafka.consumer.commit.interval:#{T(java.time.Duration).of(5, T(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit).SECONDS)}}")
private Duration commitInterval;
```

however as you can see it is a bit verbose.
or a bit easier version as OP mentioned in comment :

```
@Value("${kafka.consumer.commit.interval:#{T(java.time.Duration).ofSeconds(5)}}")
private Duration commitInterval;
```

Comment: ```@Value("${kafka.consumer.commit.interval:#{T(java.time.Duration).ofSeconds(5)}}")``` an easier version ! :)